# Changing Background color with JavaScript for a button won't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new To javascript and having a problem that i think is very simple, but no matter what i am trying to do i can't solve this. im making a monopoly game, and i want to change the background color for the current position where the player is, after he rolled the dice. all positions are buttons and all buttons have ID's, and all of them have a blue background.
i have tried to give it an '!important', and no luck.
i have tried to do this even with the .css() with jQuery, but with no avail,

here is some of my code:

```
  <html>
     <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>
    </head>

<body onload="startPos()">
<div id="dialog"></div>
<div>
<span id="die1"></span>
<span id="die2"></span>
<button id="Roll" onclick ="dice()">Roll dice!</button>
<button id="MovePlayer" onclick="move()">Move Player</button>
<span id="DisplayMoney"></span>$
</div><br/></br></br>

<button id="btop1"  disabled = "true"> City1</button>
<button id="btop2"  disabled = "true"> City1</button>
<button id="btop3"  disabled = "true"> City1</button>
<button id="btop4"  disabled = "true"> Train</button>
<button id="btop5"  disabled = "true"> City2</button>
<button id="btop6"  disabled = "true"> City2</button>
<button id="btop7"  disabled = "true"> City2</button>
<button id="btop8"  disabled = "true"> Jail</button>
<button id="btop9"  disabled = "true"> City1</button>
<button id="btop10" disabled = "true"> City1</button>
<button id="btop11" disabled = "true"> City1</button>
<button id="btop12" disabled = "true"> Train</button>
<button id="btop13" disabled = "true"> City2</button>
<button id="btop14" disabled = "true"> City2</button>
<button id="btop15" disabled = "true"> City2</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and here is the function in my javascript that responsible for moving the player:

```
     pos1=1;
     function move(){ 
        /* old= old position, pos/cur=the position where
          the player goes after rolling the dice */

old = document.getElementById("btop"+pos1);
old.disabled = true;
old.innerHTML=bname;
pos1=pos1+dicesum;
pos="btop"+pos1;
var cur = document.getElementById(pos);
bname=cur.innerHTML;
cur.innerHTML=content;
cur.disabled = false;
cur.style.backgroundColor="red";
var ans = confirm("Would you like to do something here?");
if(ans==true){
    makeAction();
}
}
```

The dice function:

```
function dice (){
    console.log("dice function invoked");
    var dice1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    var dice2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    dicesum = dice1 + dice2;

    //Placing the dice pictures
    var d1 = document.getElementById("die1");
    var d2 = document.getElementById("die2");

    switch(dice1)
    {
    case 1: 
           d1.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/one.jpg\'>';
           break;


    case 2: 
           d1.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/two.jpg\'>';
           break;

    case 3: 
           d1.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/three.jpg\'>';
           break;

    case 4: 
           d1.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/four.jpg\'>';
           break;


    case 5: 
           d1.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/five.jpg\'>';
           break;


    case 6: 
           d1.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/six.jpg\'>';
           break;          



    }

     switch(dice2)
    {
    case 1: 
           d2.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/one.jpg\'>';
           break;


    case 2: 
           d2.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/two.jpg\'>';
           break;

    case 3: 
           d2.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/three.jpg\'>';
           break;

    case 4: 
           d2.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/four.jpg\'>';
           break;


    case 5: 
           d2.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/five.jpg\'>';
           break;


    case 6: 
           d2.innerHTML = '<img src=\'Photos/Dice/six.jpg\'>';
           break;          



    }



}
```

and the css for the buttons:

```
button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: linear-gradient( #66b2ff, #e5f2ff);

}

#Roll{
    width: 50px !important;
    background: linear-gradient( #ff6666, #ffcccc) !important; 
}
#MovePlayer{
    width: 50px !important;
    background: linear-gradient( #ff6666, #ffcccc) !important; 
}
```

I am sure its a simple thing that i just cant see, just because i am a noob
in JavaScript. and for that, im turning to you guys(and girls!).
I hope i made every thing clear, if not i will answer.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: where is your `dice` function defined?

Comment: in the JavaScript file. i have not writen it here, i will if that is necessary. it just make random numbers from 1-6. i have added it to the code above.

Comment: can you make a small jsfiddle plz

Answer (score 0):

I have made jsfiddle for you ... you just want to change button colors .. right ? See my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/tzmee4te/1/)

```
 <button id="btop1" class="yo" disabled = "true"> City1</button>
<button id="btop2"  class="yo"  disabled = "true"> City2</button>
<button id="btop3" class="yo"  disabled = "true"> City3</button>
<button id="btop4" class="yo"  disabled = "true"> City4</button>
<button id="btop5" class="yo"  disabled = "true"> City5</button>
<button id="btop6" class="yo" disabled = "true"> City6</button>

<br/>
<button id="green"  > throw dice</button>



$("#green").click(function(e){
window.yoyo=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
alert("You got "+window.yoyo);
$(".yo").css("background-color","white");
$("#btop"+window.yoyo).css("background-color","green");
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzmee4te/1/)

Comment: First of all,  thanks for trying to help.  But what I wanted is,  when the player press "roll dice",  and then on move player,  he goes to that place.  In that place I want to change the background color,  so the user will know where he is.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm unable to do for some reason.

Comment: check my demo now ... see my answer ... i think you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/tzmee4te/1/

Comment: I think you got it.  Can you tell me how to incorporate it with my code?  Because I think this is the solution, but I seem to not able to place this in my code.  Can you please incorporate it in my  ode above,  that when the user press it,  it will change like in your code here?  Thank you very much.

Comment: your dicesum  variable should be global ... do like this in your dice function window.dicesum = dice1 + dice2;  and put pos1=1; inside move function ,,, it should be the first statement

Comment: well, I'm trying to implement your code for half an hour, to no avail. can you please insert it into my code above, so I can work with your solution? sorry for being such a noob here, but you're may only help here. thank you very much, my friend.

Comment: @GabrielMichaeli : since you have included jquery.js ,,, so you can use jquery ... i have edited your code ,,, see this  https://jsfiddle.net/rvcs3nuu/

Comment: Thank you very much. you have been really helpful.